# Find maximum height of a ball rolling up an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics

You roll a ball up a 30° incline with an initial velocity of $10$ m/s. How far up
the ramp does the ball travel? You can ignore friction.

This is a problem from my physics exam review worksheet and I am very stuck. I applied conservation of energy without taking into account the ramp and was off by a factor of 2.

I don't know how to incorporate the angle into the problem. I tried doing a similar thing to what I usually do with kinematics, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That ball has two forms of energy as it rolls towards the incline.  Those are kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy.  Rotational kinetic energy depends on the "shape" of the ball (i.e., solid, thin spherical shell, thick shell, etc.).  As noted by "Community", your question can't be answered without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Conservation of energy gives you the total height gained, $h = v^2/2g$

Since the ball doesn't travel straight up the length of the path on the ramp is longer. Height and length of the ramp form a rectangular triangle with the ground, so the path travelled, $d$ is simply

$$d = \frac{h}{\sin(\alpha)}$$

That's your factor of two.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a solid sphere rolling up an incline, kinetic energy goes to potential energy (assuming no loss to friction): (1/2)m${v^2} + (1/2)[(2/5)m{R^2}](v/R)^2$ = mgL sin(30). (where (L) is the distance straight up the incline.)